# Giving IDs to groups in R

Tags: r

I have in R data frame that is divided to groups, like this:

| Row | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | A |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | C |
| 6 | B |
| 7 | C |
| 8 | C |
| 9 | A |
| 10 | B |

I would like to add a uniaque numeric ID to each group, so finally I would have something like this:

| Row | Group | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 3 | A | 1 |
| 4 | D | 4 |
| 5 | C | 3 |
| 6 | B | 2 |
| 7 | C | 3 |
| 8 | C | 3 |
| 9 | A | 1 |
| 10 | B | 2 |

How could I achieve this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can use `match` `df1$ID = with(df1, match(Group, sort(unique(Group))))`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `match` on the `sort`ed `unique` values of 'Group' on the 'Group' to get the position index

```
df1$ID <- with(df1, match(Group, sort(unique(Group))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Row = 1:10, Group = c("A", "B", "A", "D", "C", 
"B", "C", "C", "A", "B")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

`group_indices()` was deprecated in **dplyr 1.0.0**.

Please use `cur_group_id()` instead.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id())
```

**First answer:**

You can use `group_indices`

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(ID = group_indices())
```

data

```
df <- tribble(
~Row,   ~Group,
1, "A", 
2, "B", 
3, "A", 
4, "D", 
5, "C", 
6, "B", 
7, "C", 
8, "C", 
9, "A", 
10,"B")
```

```
     Row Group    ID
   <int> <chr> <int>
 1     1 A         1
 2     2 B         2
 3     3 A         1
 4     4 D         4
 5     5 C         3
 6     6 B         2
 7     7 C         3
 8     8 C         3
 9     9 A         1
10    10 B         2
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way.

```
df1$ID <- as.integer(factor(df1$Group))
```

---

There are 3 solutions posted, mine, [TarJae's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618399/8245406) and [akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618365/8245406), timed with increasing data sizes. [akrun's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66618365/8245406) is the fastest.

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

funtest <- function(x, n){
  out <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(i){
    for(j in seq_len(i)) x <- rbind(x, x)
    cat("nrow(x):", nrow(x), "\n")
    mb <- microbenchmark(
      match = with(x, match(Group, sort(unique(Group)))),
      dplyr = x %>% group_by(Group) %>% mutate(ID = cur_group_id()),
      intfac = as.integer(factor(x$Group))
    )
    mb$n <- i
    mb
  })
  out <- do.call(rbind, out)
  aggregate(time ~ ., out, median)
}

df1 %>%
  funtest(10) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n, time, colour = expr)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:10, labels = 1:10) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]